# Database ER Diagram of a Multi-tenant System

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

We are designing a multi-tenant system and we want to employ The shared database, Schema sharing, shared data table.

Since Our Tenants could be State (US States), County or Individual Organizations. The following figure depicts a high level view. (Where O1,O2.. are Organizations, and U1,U2.. are users)

[image: High Level Requirement]

1. A **state** can have many **organizations** under it.
2. An **Organization** will one or more **User** under it.
3. An **Organization** can have one or more **Organizations** (**sub organization**) under it.
4. A **User** from one **organization** cannot belong to other **organization**.
5. Every **Tenant** will have its own **Admin** who can perform CRUD on **Organization**/**User** (Ex Creating **Organization** and assigning **User** to **Organizations**)
6. A **SuperAdmin** (from our Company) will be able to activate/deactivate any **Tenant**.

Below is a high level ER diagram. Since tables are shared between tenants, we have a **tenant_id** column in all tables.

Since an organizations can be nested under an organization, I am thinking of having a self referencing table with **Discriminator Column**.

I am looking for inputs to optimize/correct this ER Diagram and before anyone starts yelling at the ER, I would like to mention that I am a programmer and not a DB expert :).

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to have a look at Bill Karwins slides to SQL antipatterns, i.e. http://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back Naive trees are coming to my mind.

Comment: I would consider postgresql here, as it has totally segregated databases (which you might find useful for orgs that should never see each other), and does hierarchical querying better than mysql.